# Is it possible force TabLayout to use dynamic TabLayout.Tab width based on TabLayout.Tab text length?

Tags: android, dynamic, tabs, width, android-tablayout

I have TabLayout where I have to use texts with different length. It means text can be 4-5 characters long or it can be 10-12 characters long. And what TabLayout does, it takes longest text and based on it, it set TabLayout.Tab width to all TabLayout.Tabs. But this doesn´t look nice. Is there any way to change it, so there will be always same spacing between texts no matter how long it will be?

Note for picture: I would like to change it from top image to bottom image.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. Key is set "**app:tabMinWidth**" to zero and then set how much space between tabs we need with **app:tabPaddingStart** & **app:tabPaddingEnd**.

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_layout_height"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="10dp"
    app:tabPaddingStart="10dp"
    app:tabMinWidth="0dp" />
```

Comment: Its not working for me

Answer (score 1):

Please add `app:tabMode="scrollable"` to your `<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout/>`

Comment: Already tried this, it just make it scrollable, but tabs widths are same.